# How can I add a IDataReader object to List<IDataReader> in C#?

Tags: c#, recursion, idatareader

How can I create and add n `IDataReader` objects to a `List<IDataReader>`?

Comment: `var readers = new List<IDataReader>()`

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking for, but don't you just need the [List<T>.Add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: `readers.Add(someDbCommand.ExecuteReader());` See also [IDbCommand.ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcdcxtt0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @aydoğdudemirci How did it go? Is your problem solved now?

Comment: @PJvG yes. `readers.Add(someDbCommand.ExecuteReader())` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create and add n `IDataReader` objects to `List<IDataReader>`?

```
readers.Add(someDbCommand.ExecuteReader());
```

See also [IDbCommand.ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcdcxtt0(v=vs.110).aspx)